# Oracle Query for joining on same column

Tags: oracle, self-join

How do I join on same column for different values and both the values should be `and` condition?

```
eg: TABLEA.COLUMNA='XYZ' AND TABLEB.COLUMNA='PQR'
```

Please note `TableA` and `TableB` are same table.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  The `ON` clause you showed us could be part of a valid self join query, but since you did not show the entire query or any data, this is not certain.

Answer (score 0):

From your tagging you know need a self-join, in which two instances of the table are joined to each other. That's as simple as you would hope it would be:

```
select a.id as a_id
       , b.id as b_id
from your_table a
     cross join your_table b
where a.columnA = 'XYZ'
and b.columnA = 'PQR'
```

This query doesn't make sense logically. The cross join will produce a product of all the permutations of `a.id, b.id`. You probably don't want that. Maybe  you want something like this:

```
select a.id as a_id
       , b.id as b_id
from your_table a
     join your_table b
       on a.some_other_column = b.some_other_column
where a.columnA = 'XYZ'
and b.columnA = 'PQR'
```

But you didn't post all your criteria so only you know for sure.